# Regarding the "être" verbs like "venir", "sortir": What are some examples where the present tense is used to talk about the immediate past?

Tags: usage, temps-grammatical

The most prominent example would be the verb "**venir**":

> La Lexus CT 200h **vient** tout juste d'être lancée en Europe.
>
> {instead of}: La Lexus CT 200h **a** tout juste **été** lancée en Europe.

Coupled often with "(tout) juste", the verb "venir" always takes the present tense, not Passé Composé, to refer to the immediate past.

Now I wonder if this tendency extends to other "être" verbs such as "sortir" that take "être" instead of "avoir" for the Passé Composé form:

> Moi je **sors** tout juste de ma période d'hibernation.
>
> {instead of}: Moi je **suis** tout juste **sorti** de ma période d'hibernation.

What are other similar examples?

Comment: I know of no other verb that could stand in for *venir de* in that example, including *sortir de*, with the same meaning. (In school French, anyway.) The phrase is no longer lexical but grammaticalized, hence not interchangeable with similar verbs.

Comment: Whether there are other *constructions* that perform the same function I'll have to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imperfect is possible as well in *aller faire* and *venir de faire* used as auxiliary temporal constructions. I believe the imperfect aspect is forced by the meaning.

If you say

> La Lexus CT 200h venait tout juste d'être lancée en Europe.

you necessarily talk about a past time. Note that historic present could also be used in some cases.

Concerning normal verbs, I can't see any difference in tense usage that could be related to the auxiliary verb that is used for compound tenses.

Comment: Hi. Imparfait is indeed possible, but my focus here is on instances where Présent is preferred to Passé Composé. Can you think of other examples?

Comment: Passé composé doesn't have an imperfect aspect, so it's ruled out.

Comment: @Alone-zee: Ah, ok. So by “passé composé” you meant without using *venir de*. Then yes, immediate past for the present moment is always rendered with an auxiliary in the present tense. But this is basic knowlegde. I think you get slightly confused by something, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: Maybe the passive construction is unnecessarily confusing. Try to think about an active voice example?

Comment: Hi. I'm not confused by the meaning of this construction, but rather I'm looking for other similar examples like "sortir". :)

Comment: *Je décide tout juste. J'ai tout juste décidé*. It's not specific to verbs that use *être*. It just happens that *tout juste* works well with many of the *être* verbs, because many are about movement or status change (including passive voice).

Comment: Hi. Do you think I've got the following three right? {Immediate Past}: "***je viens tout juste d'entrer*** dans mon 7ème mois de grossesse". {Immediate Past}: "***j'entre tout juste*** dans mon 7ème mois de grossesse". {Immediate Past}: "***j'entre*** dans mon 7ème mois de grossesse".